# Are answers that just contain a link acceptable?

Tags: discussion, answers

If somebody answers by just putting a link, is the answer acceptable?
Should the answer be flagged as "not an answer"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been covered numerous times previously; the most thorough being the MSO post, [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Short version: it's a *really* bad idea.

A link isn't an answer; it's just a pointer to a possible answer. With no context, someone seeing just a link doesn't know if it might be on-topic, off-topic, a joke, or spam. Even a little bit of context helps make it clear *why* the link is worth following.

Additionally, answers here should be for the long term. If someone has the same problem two years from now, the link that's currently to a great blog post may well later be a 404 (or worse). If the link was the entire answer, then Apple.SE no longer has an answer for the question.

#### Link-only answers should be flagged as what they are: not answers.

Comment: Is it better to flag them or edit them? Editing would prevent the link appearing multiple times on the same Q&A, but then again it *might* generate false-reputation for the link's provider. (But isn't the Stack Exchange about quality and community rather than rep?)

Comment: we've already seen link-only answers become useless on SO a bunch of times when the underlying link starts to 404. So you really do need to insist that answers contain a relevant excerpt that is *the answer*

Comment: What did I oversee on flagging this answer? The flag was declined, I'd like to avoid wrong flagging, but would have seen this as link only answer.

Comment: The same question would fit for this answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/92701/55266